# rails ajax spinner works in development but not production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am using this javascript:

```
verify_link.js
  ...
  a=$(this).parent();
  a.html('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif">');
  ...
```

The image is in `app/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif`

Works ok in developmnent but in production it get a broken image link (is a little hard to see but is not the spinner).

Would using a rails path fix this ?

Currently it is a `.js file`, do I need to make it `.js.erb` to do that ?

Comment: What error or unexpected behavior do you get in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the file extension from .js to .js.erb and using

```
a.html('<%= image_tag "ajax-loader.gif" %>');
```

Fixed it.